# Remove newline characters in my data with Duckdb

Tags: csv, duckdb

I've received a csv file with some issues, I've noticed a few issues when attempting to load into BigQuery.
I'm using duckdb to quickly sanitise the data, and I'm noticing a bunch of newline characters in my data.

Is there a quick way to remove newlines from duckdb data before I write back out to csv?

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses \n for a new-line, Windows \r\n and old Macs \r.

So essentially, what solved it for me was

`select * from table where regexp_matches(bad_column, ['\r\n']);`

then I could run

`delete from table where id in (select id from table where regexp_matches(bad_column, ['\r\n']));`

Comment: Have you removed the records? Wasn't it better to just remove the carriage returns?